# Is it mathematically correct to use P(z|x) & P(x|z) to refer Encoder & Decoder respectively in Deep Learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, notation

There are tons of research papers about neural network, for example, VAEs simply call its Encoder & Decoder by `P(z|x)` & `P(x|z)` respectively.

Although I get what people try to say, I still find it's not strictly correct to simply use e.g. `P(x|z)` to notate Decoder, and there are several reasons:

1. `P(X)`, in general, is probability. Therefore, e.g. `P(x|z)` as Decoder should output probability, however, in many actual code and implementation, the Decoder neural network outputs a value for each pixel of the image, either in range [0,1] or [0,255], and they are not probability.
2. One explanation for the single value for each pixel mentioned above is that people assume each pixel value returned from the Decoder network is the mean for a normal distribution while the variance is to be assumed(not calculated). Then the `P(x|z)` as Decoder outputs the mean value for each pixel, not exactly a probability, doesn't it? Therefore, it seems incorrect to use `P(x|z)` as Decoder, as `P(x|z)` should be probability.

In short, my question is, p(x|z) refers a model that supposes to output probability, but the implementation level people do not follow the meaning of probability and their code actually outputs a single value for each pixel of an image. I hope people can explain if it's incorrect notation in research papers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is about _programming_, but the question is about math, probability theory or ML theory. You could probably ask this on Cross Validated.

Comment: Encoder and decoder are usually written lower case (`p(x|z)` and `p(z|x)`).  You are reading too much into the similarity with `P(x)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts After changing the upper case to lower case, my question still exists. `p()` is reserved for probability: `p(x|z)` means given z, the probability of x. And I don't think I am reading too much, because when those papers talk about training loss or Jensen's inequality, they refer `p(x|z)` as probability in those equations.

Comment: @ForceBru I believe those who try to run codes provided by those papers would find such discussion valuable here too. But I'll try to post this in Cross Validated too, thx.

Answer (score -1):

You're misunderstanding the notations and your answer to Tim Robert's comment is incorrect. For decoders, it means the probability of getting output image x given latent variables z. They are just making the point that it is not a deterministic model and it is a simple way to indicate the direction of operation.

Adding another example for Jason.
Basic probability - let's say we have a classifier for mnist with 10 digits. The output for each is a probability for each category. Let's say input is a 1, the output could be [0.01, 0.8, 0.2, .... ]. Here, we would say p(1|1) = 0.8. It is clear, and I think this is what you expect.

But - if we take a mini-corpus "This one is a big one guys." we can still meaningfully say that P(is|one) = 0.5 when an NLP model directly outputs the word 'is' given an input of 'one' without ever seeing a probability value, and our understanding that this is a probabilistic model is still correct.

You are confusing output with behaviour, I think.

Comment: If the model does not output "probability", then you shouldn't use a probability `p(x|z)` to refer such thing that that does not give probability. Again, the neural network outputs single value for each pixel. The notation for probability `p(x|z)` in such case is confusing.

Comment: This notation is used largely by research papers, and people reading the papers suppose to be able to follow their work to reproduce their results. Now if the author says the Decoder is `p(x|z)`, then reader should exactly expect this neural network outputs probability. If you think it's the readers' fault for being misunderstanding, then what do you think `p(x|z)` is when you look at them without pre-determined knowledge?

Comment: No, you misunderstand probability theory. P(x) notation doesn't ever mean the model outputs a probability. It means there is a probability of X occuring. In this case, a probability that a specific image is output by the model, given the latent variables.

Comment: I believe we all remember simple example like this `P(x=rian tmr) = 0.6`. `P(x)` refers a probability. If you review some of the most basic the statistics questions, there is no doubt. In fact, your answer double mouth itself, you mentioned "there is a probability of X occuring", then there is a probability, which is a real value, the probability of something happening. In my original question, people use `P(x|z)` to refer a neural network and also use it to calculate the Jensen's inequality in the VAE context.

Comment: Well, the bottom line is that your objections are irrelevant.  The community has established a well-defined meaning for those expressions.  Whether that meaning happens to line up with your narrow interpretation doesn't really matter.  You need to widen your expectations to include the reality.

Comment: @TimRoberts well-established ambiguous or misleading notations do not mean it's the right one. This question is valid, it brings more clarity to more people. It's because your so-called "narrow" interpretation that makes things clear and exact. And, only because of many others use the notation that way, you feel secure about your opinion and negate the question in this post, won't help anything.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your example. I try to focus on the VAE case, where the model outputs a value for each pixel of an image, the value ranging from either `[0,1]`(will be converted to [0,255] to properly display image later) or `[0,255]`(directly) for pixel value. The question comes, when people use this notation `P(x|z)` to refer Decoder network, although we all know what the actual neural network does, which is outputting pixel value, the notation `P(x|z)` means probability, which is not what the model returns. There is a misleading. They do use notation `P(x|z)` for probability calculation.